# React Animating reordering of Items

Tags: css, html, reactjs, css-animations

When I close that expanding box, I would like the other list items to transition smoothly back to their original position and not jump like they are doing now.  How can I achieve that, I have no idea how to tackle this problem.

[image]

Edit: The Listitems are an array of Components. The Expandable is toggled with an OnClickEvent, which changes a bool in the state and a conditional rendering quote, like this:

`{this.state.expanded && <div> Expandable </div>`

Comment: Maybe if post some code it would be easier

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work the way I wanted by animating the height of the Expandable window. Just for future reference I am using the React CSSTransitionGroup to animate that Expandable.

Here is the result:

[image]

Still have to do some fine tuning though

If someone else finds a better solution though feel free to post it, since I learned you should try to avoid to animate any property, but: opacity, scale, position and rotation